# Enabling password free software installation with parental controls on to block adult content

Tags: macos, parental-controls

I'm trying to have my son's computer setup so he can still install software with certain parental controls still active.

It seems there's no way to bypass the password window coming up when installing software, which is a pain.

Answer (score 2):

The password window shows up when an app needs administrator access to access certain files or folders not in the user's home directory.

You may be able to bypass this, depending on how the application is distributed.

- If the application is distributed by itself or in an archive(such as a `.dmg` or `.zip`) that just contains the app with no installer, you can drag-and-drop the application to the user's Applications folder(`/Users/[your username]/Applications/`) instead of the system Applications folder(`/Applications/`). If the user's Applications folder doesn't exist, you can create it yourself.
- If the application is distributed as `.pkg` installer, it may provide the option for you during installation to "Install for me only" which will not require an administrator password.

Comment: In other words it is up to the app developer, depending on what the app needs to do on the system, whether or not installation requires admin rights.